# Changing starting view in AvaloniaUI project

Tags: avaloniaui

I want to change starting view. It displays MainWindow by default.
I created Start view with cli command and Start view model similarly to MainWindow files.

When I add lines:

```
<Design.DataContext>
    <vm:StartViewModel/>
</Design.DataContext>
```

to Start.xaml file I get and error:

`System.Xaml.XamlException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`

And when I try to replace MainWindow with Start in App file like this:

```
public class App : Application
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
    }

    public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
    {
        if (ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
        {
            desktop.MainWindow = new Start
            {
                DataContext = new StartViewModel()
            };
        }

        base.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();
    }
}
```

I get:

`The type or namespace "Start "could not be found.`

How can I make this work ?

Comment: >System.Xaml.XamlException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Most likely caused by the recent VS update. Visual Studio enforces WPF designer for all XAML files because they ignore 3rd-party XAML technologies.

Try using `.paml` file extension as a workaround.

Comment: I think this is the same issue: [link](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/4037). Unfortunately using .paml extension doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to your view code-behind contains this DemoProject.Views where DemoProject is the name of your project